# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'withSuccessHandler')

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api, add-on

I'm trying to call my **code. gs** functions on the click of a **button**. When I execute the function at that time it shows an **error** that  **Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'withSuccessHandler')**. I tested that when I'm executing the **printNameToSheet** function without **withSuccessHandler** and **withFailureHandler** at that time it's working fine. If I add these two functions to the **printNameToSheet** then it's showing an error.
The code works fine if I removed both functions. But I want to add both functions to the **printNameToSheet**, so that I can catch the **success** and **error** of **functions**.

I had pasted the code of the **app** and **code**. gs file. I have attached the **screenshot** of the error at last.

Can anyone guide me on this error.?
**code.gs**

```
function onOpen() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
    .createMenu('Custom Menu')
    .addItem('Show sidebar', 'showSidebar')
    .addToUi();
}

function doGet() {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('app');
}

function include(filename) {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile(filename)
    .getContent();
}

function showSidebar() {
  var html = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('app').evaluate().setTitle("Test Addon")
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
    .showSidebar(html);
}

function getName() {
  return "Alex"
}

function printNameToSheet(name) {
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet()
  sheet.getActiveCell().setValue(name)
}
```

**app.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <base target="_top">
</head>

<body>
  <button onclick="getNameAndPrint()">CLICK ME</button>
</body>
<script>
  function onFailure(error){
    console.log(error.message)
  }

  function getNameAndPrint(){
      google.script.run
        .withFailureHandler(onFailure)
        .withSuccessHandler(function(name){
          console.log(name);

          google.script.run
          .printNameToSheet(name)
          .withSuccessHandler(function(){
            console.log("Process Completed")
          })
          .withFailureHandler(onFailure)
        })
        .getName()
  }
</script>
</html>
```

[image: Error Image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have checked your code and the error is coming from ‘app.html’ specifically, in the following section:

```
   google.script.run
          .printNameToSheet(name)
          .withSuccessHandler(function(){
            console.log("Process Completed")
          })
          .withFailureHandler(onFailure)
        })
        .getName()
```

The class [google.script.run](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run#index.html_2) is the one providing access to the method *“withSuccessHandler()”*, but in your code, you added the function first causing the ‘undefined’ error to appear in the console. That being said, I suggest the following update ‘app.html’:

```
<script>
  function onFailure(error){
    console.log(error.message)
  }

  function getNameAndPrint(){
      google.script.run
        .withFailureHandler(onFailure)
        .withSuccessHandler(function(name){
          console.log(name);
          
          google.script.run  
          .withSuccessHandler(function(){
            console.log("Process Completed")
          })
          .withFailureHandler(onFailure)
          .printNameToSheet(name)
        })
        .getName()
  }
</script>
```

#### References:

- [Class google.script.run](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run#index.html_2)

p.s: my apologies if my explanation wasn't clear enough. If you have any questions, let me know!

Comment: Is there any order matter in calling the Google script functions?
I noticed that when I right withSucessHandle first and after that my function printNameToSheet(name) it's working fine. otherwise it's going to be giving error.